# generating a matrix based on values of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

I am working in Python. I have 3 arrays (10,1) called a, b and c. I have a dataframe (3,2) called index which contains either a, b, c or nan. For example:

```
index = [['a', 'NaN', 'b'], ['b', 'c', NaN]]
```

Now i want to generate a matrix called Summary which should contain 4 columns: `a,b,b,c`

```
a = np.random.rand(10,1)
b = np.random.rand(10,1)
c = np.random.rand(10,1)
index = [['a', 'NaN', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'NaN']]
```

I want to go to index and look for names of variables and stack them horizontally in a matrix called Summary according to index.

So in this case i should obtain a matrix (10,4) where the first column is a, the second b, the third b, the fourth c.

Comment: So for this example you want a matrix with 40 rows and 10 columns?

Comment: sorry. i mean the vectors a b and c are 10 ,1. So i should obtain a 10,4